# Giving a Docker container configuration access to a device

Tags: docker

If I understand the docs correctly, `--device` gives privileged access to the listed device. When I run a container that needs to manipulate `/dev/uio0` with the line:

```
docker run --device=/dev/uio0:/dev/uio0 rakurai/ovs-dpdk
```

I get an error like:

```
EAL: Cannot open /sys/class/uio/uio0/device/config: Read-only file system
```

I can get past that error if I used `--privileged`, but I'd like the access to be a little more restricted. I have tried to the container write access with:

```
-v /sys/class/uio/uio0:/sys/class/uio/uio0
```

but to no avail. Is there a convenient way to give the container access to the device configuration?

Comment: Have you tried: `docker run --device=/dev/uio0 rakurai/ovs-dpdk`?